# VLC WebPlugin subtitle not working

Tags: javascript, plugins, vlc

I'm using the latest version of VLC's WebPlugin to play an MKV video with subtitles. I'm having the issue that every time I set `subtitle.track` to `1` (which `subtitle.description(1)` gives the output of [English]", it changes itself back to `-1`. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out myself. It turns out that (although undocumented), you do not set `subtitle.track` to the track number of the subtitle, but rather the **stream track**.

In my case the tracks were:

- 0 - Video
- 1 - Audio (english)
- 2 - Audio (swedish)
- 3 - ***Subtitles***!!

So setting `subtitle.track` to `3` worked perfectly.